# Saving multiple canvas controls as an image in silverlight/wpf

Tags: wpf, silverlight, image

I have a situation where I have a canvas with an image and I lay multiple canvas controls over it and each canvas may have multiple controls drawn on them (Ellipses, Lines, etc).  What is the best/most efficient way to save all these canvas controls toone image?   I assume WritableBitmap, but how will this work with multiple canvas controls?  One given is that each canvas will be the same size.

EDIT:

This is what I tried.  I also tried with the dpi of the original image, which gives me the tiny result.

```
BitmapSource bms = (BitmapSource)this.ctlImage.Source;

Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this.ctlImgCanvas).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice; 

RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(bms.PixelWidth, bms.PixelHeight, m.M11 * 96.0, m.M22 * 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

rtb.Render(this.ctlImgCanvas);

PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
            encoder.Save(memStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take care of everything including children of the canvas. You don't need to know the size of the canvas in advance.

```
Matrix m =
PresentationSource.FromVisual(canvas).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

BitmapSource panelBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                (int)Math.Floor(canvas.ActualWidth),
                (int)Math.Floor(canvas.ActualHeight),
                m.M11 * 96.0, // For DPI. This hardcoded value is correct. Check WPF DPI
                m.M22 * 96.0, 
                PixelFormats.Default);

panelBitmap.Render(canvas);

using (FileStream fs = File.Open([filename], FileModel.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = GetBitmapEncoderForFileExtension([filename]); // See documentation for which encoder to use when.
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(panelBitmap ));
    encoder.Save(fs);
}
```

Comment: This works for WPF.  I ended up using ImageTools for silverlight.

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap will only construct with PixelFormats.Pbgra32 and my image end s up being the right height and width but the actual image is shrunk way down in the upper left of the image.  Any idea why?

Comment: What is ctlImage? What is its relation to ctlCanvas? What is the source property? How is it calculated?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Hasty cut and paste.  ctlImageCanvas is the Canvas I want to export.  ctlImage is an Image and the child of ctlImageCanvas.  ctlImage.Source is a Uri pointing to a jpeg on the server.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You asked how to take an a snap of a canvas and all its child elements to the bitmap. In your code you are using the size of the image to calculate the size of the rendered bitmap. Then you are copying the canvas to the bitmap using the size of the image. What exactly do you want? Doesn't make any sense. The RenderTargetBitmap should be of the same size at that of the canvas you want to take an image of. The ctlImage should be nowhere in the picture. Why do you think bms.PixelWidth/bms.PixelWidth should give you size of the canvas?

Comment: My bad.  I'm using a scaleTransform on the canvas, thats what was messing it up.  I used ImageTools to do this in SL and that was not an issue, I guess I assumed it wouldn't be with RenderTargetBitmap.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Save the container of the Canvas's to a bitmap, it'll pick up all the children.